# Regarding p2p connection across the internet and c#. Again

Tags: c#, wcf, p2p

This topic resembles [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183459/direct-p2p-connection) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735869/regarding-p2p-connection-and-c-sharp). Also I have read [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/cc297274(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
But, in any of this thread I can't find clear example how organize p2p connection **across the internet**.
All examples good working in local network.

I made a small program, you can see it below. It works good in local network.

Main question: After peer registration how to open Wcf host and wait calls from another peers? In [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735869/regarding-p2p-connection-and-c-sharp) I have read that:

> When a peer is resolved on the global cloud, it is typically resolved to an IPv6 address

So I need open my WCF on this IPv6 address? How I can receive it?
Please give me some coding tips.

My program:

```
namespace FileShare
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello enter your username");

            IPeerRegistrationRepository peerRegistrationRepository = new PeerRegistrationRepository();
            IPeerNameResolverRepository peerNameResolverRepository = new PeerNameResolverRepository();
            ServiceHost host = null;

            try
            {

                string username = Console.ReadLine();

                int port = PeerUtils.FindFreePort();

                peerRegistrationRepository.StartRegistration("Max951Peer", port, PeerNameType.Secured);

                string serviceUrl = $"net.tcp://{peerRegistrationRepository.PeerName.PeerHostName}:{port}/Max951P2PService";

                IP2PService localService = new P2PService();
                host = new ServiceHost(localService, new Uri(serviceUrl));
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IP2PService), new NetTcpBinding { Security = { Mode = SecurityMode.None } }, serviceUrl);

                try
                {
                    host.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Host opened on { serviceUrl }");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error { e }");

                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Registered peer. PeerHostName: { peerRegistrationRepository.PeerName.PeerHostName }, Classifier: { peerRegistrationRepository.PeerName.Classifier }");

                PeerNameRecordCollection results = peerNameResolverRepository.ResolvePeerName(peerRegistrationRepository.PeerName, Cloud.Global);

                Console.WriteLine("{0} Peers Found:", results.Count.ToString());
                int i = 1;

                foreach (PeerNameRecord peer in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Peer:{1}", i++, peer.PeerName);

                    foreach (IPEndPoint ip in peer.EndPointCollection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t Endpoint: {0}", ip);

                        string endpointUrl = $"net.tcp://[{ip.Address}]:{ip.Port}/Max951P2PService";

                        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding { Security = { Mode = SecurityMode.None } };

                        try
                        {
                            IP2PService serviceProxy = ChannelFactory<IP2PService>.CreateChannel(binding, new EndpointAddress(endpointUrl));

                            serviceProxy.SendMessage("Hello!", username);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            // ignored
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                peerRegistrationRepository.StopRegistration();
                host?.Close();
            }

            //serviceModelClient.Stop();
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IP2PService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void SendMessage(string message, string from);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class P2PService : IP2PService
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public void SendMessage(string message, string from)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{from} says: { message }");
        }
    }
}

namespace Utils.PeerToPeer
{
    public class PeerNameResolverRepository : IPeerNameResolverRepository
    {
        private readonly PeerNameResolver peerNameResolver;

        public PeerNameResolverRepository()
        {
            this.peerNameResolver = new PeerNameResolver();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public PeerNameRecordCollection ResolvePeerName(string name, PeerNameType peerNameType, Cloud cloud)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }

            return this.peerNameResolver.Resolve(new PeerName(name, peerNameType), cloud);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public PeerNameRecordCollection ResolvePeerName(PeerName peerName, Cloud cloud)
        {
            return this.peerNameResolver.Resolve(peerName, cloud);
        }
    }
}

namespace Utils.PeerToPeer
{
    public class PeerRegistrationRepository : IPeerRegistrationRepository
    {
        private PeerNameRegistration peerNameRegistration;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool IsRegistered => this.peerNameRegistration != null && this.peerNameRegistration.IsRegistered();

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public string PeerUri => GetPeerUri();

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public PeerName PeerName { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public void StartRegistration(string name, int port, PeerNameType peerNameType)
        {
            this.PeerName = new PeerName(name, peerNameType);
            this.peerNameRegistration = new PeerNameRegistration(PeerName, port, Cloud.Global);

            this.peerNameRegistration.Start();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public void StopRegistration()
        {
            this.peerNameRegistration?.Stop();

            this.peerNameRegistration = null;
        }

        private string GetPeerUri()
        {
            return this.peerNameRegistration?.PeerName.PeerHostName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WCF wouldn't be my first choice for this.

Comment: For information about P2P in WCF, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/peer-to-peer-networking